# Как оптимизировать события в коде - JS?

Tags: javascript, ооп, события, оптимизация

Вот код:

```
const filter = () => {
const menu = document.querySelector('.portfolio-menu'),
      items = menu.querySelectorAll('li'),
      btnAll = menu.querySelector('.all'),
      btnLovers = menu.querySelector('.lovers'),
      btnChef = menu.querySelector('.chef'),
      btnGirl = menu.querySelector('.girl'),
      btnGuy = menu.querySelector('.guy'),
      btnGrandmother = menu.querySelector('.grandmother'),
      btnGranddad= menu.querySelector('.granddad'),
      wrapper = document.querySelector('.portfolio-wrapper'),
      markAll = wrapper.querySelectorAll('.all'),
      markGirl = wrapper.querySelectorAll('.girl'),
      markLovers = wrapper.querySelectorAll('.lovers'),
      markChef = wrapper.querySelectorAll('.chef'),
      markGuy = wrapper.querySelectorAll('.guy'),
      no = document.querySelector('.portfolio-no');

const typeFilter = (markType) => {
    markAll.forEach(mark => {
        mark.style.display = 'none';
        mark.classList.remove('animated', 'fadeIn');
    });

    no.style.display = 'none';
    no.classList.remove('animated', 'fadeIn');

    if(markType) {
        markType.forEach(mark => {
            mark.style.display = 'block';
            mark.classList.add('animated', 'fadeIn');
        });
    } else {
        no.style.display = 'block';
        no.classList.add('animated', 'fadeIn');
    }
};

btnAll.addEventListener('click', () => {
    typeFilter(markAll);
});

btnLovers.addEventListener('click', () => {
    typeFilter(markLovers);
});

btnChef.addEventListener('click', () => {
    typeFilter(markChef);
});

btnGirl.addEventListener('click', () => {
    typeFilter(markGirl);
});

btnGuy.addEventListener('click', () => {
    typeFilter(markGuy);
});

btnGrandmother.addEventListener('click', () => {
    typeFilter();
});

btnGranddad.addEventListener('click', () => {
    typeFilter();
});

menu.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    let target = e.target;

    if(target && target.tagName == "LI"){
        items.forEach(btn => btn.classList.remove('active'));
        target.classList.add('active');
    }
}); };
```

Как мне заменить множественные вызовы **AddEventListener** и функции **typeFilter**?
Чтобы код работал также.

Comment: Записать все querySelector в массив и пройтись по елементам добавляя колбэк функцию

Comment: приложите ваш html